# Give the super high score posts less attention

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Very often you see linked questions with a score of over 1000. While they rarely are bad questions, they are very rarely several magnitudes better than a typical 10-score question. For answers this effect is a bit less, but still highly noticeable. When a question or answer gets a very high score, it usually continues to rise just because of the high score. This can easily hide precious gems out there.

To be more precise, a high score does not directly give a higher score, but a high score gives more attention, and since it gets more attention and the tendency already is giving it a + rather than -, well you get the picture. I have seen lots of good questions with corresponding answers with scores around 3. If a question does not reach over 20 within a few hours, I highly doubt it will ever come up to 50 no matter how good it is.

This is bad in two ways. The most important it that this forum misses the hidden gems out there by never giving them a fair chance. SO becomes a mainstream radio channel. Good alternative music and good mainstream music from unknown bands never get the chance to shine.

**TL;DR**

High ranked questions and answers continues to rise, not due to their quality, but to the attention they get from their current score. I think we need some way of giving attention to equally good posts that have not had the luck to become a high score post.

**Suggestions and thoughts**

I have a suggestion here, but I'm fully open for others or for reasons why this would be a bad idea.

1) Introduce a new review queue, where we review questions and answers that are a at least a week old and within the score range 0 to 50 or so, giving them a chance to pop up (or down) a few steps. I don't think we need to consider negative posts for this.

Comment: They're high scored typically because they're problems that are very commonly asked, thus making the question *very* useful. hence it's score. Why wouldn't we want to point people to them?

Comment: I'm not saying that we should not point people to them. I'm saying we should give other questions and answers a chance. Very often there's a lower score question that's MUCH more relevant.

Comment: Just so I understand: The high ranked questions are OK, and you don't dispute their score. It is just that you prefer other high ranked questions? Oh, and we're not a [forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)...

Comment: Granted, a random 10 score question has a much higher chance of being better than a random 0 score question, but I don't think you really can see that pattern after 100 or so.

Comment: Your suggestion 2 is an upvote review queue? So a review action is voting on the post?

Comment: Well, I do dispute most questions with a score of 1000 are significantly better than questions with a score of 100, and thus I don't think score is a good way of picking relevant topics above a certain level.

Comment: In what way are we giving these higher scored posts priority? If i do a few random searches (on SO), i don't get the highly scored ones first unless i sort by score or search for them specifically.

Comment: @rene Yes, that's my thought.

Comment: @KevinB The question specifically brings up the "related" section, which *does* incorporate the post's score in determining what shows up, and in what order.  It would be easy enough to say that anything after some number is all the same, for the purposes of ranking related questions.  I'm not sure of any other contexts where it would make sense, perhaps the homepage, but score is already a small enough portion of the weight there (as compared to time) that I'm not sure it's much of an issue there.

Comment: hmm.. looking at the related posts to *this* post, the highest scored isn't first. there's quite a few negatively voted ones too. is meta different?

Comment: @I realize I was wrong about that thing. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @klutt well, a voting review queue will not be implemented as it would make voters no longer anonymous.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, they're not ranked *entirely* on score, but the ranking incorporates score as a part of the weight.  As a result, a higher scored post can sometimes be put above a lowered score post with higher relevance, but *sufficiently* better relevance can overcome a lower score.

Comment: it's going to be hard for a question with 1-2 answers to overcome a question with 50 answers in terms of relevance if it also takes into account answers in that algorithm, regardless of score.

Comment: @rene How so? First posts and Late answers already works that way.

Comment: You can do any number of things in those queues besides voting.  In fact, those other actions should encompass the majority of your review actions in those queues.  That means that seeing someone as a reviewer for a post might mean that they're more likely to have voted on it than a random person, but they may well not have voted at all.  If you have a queue where they can *only* vote, then you *know* that every reviewer voted on the post, and if the post has all upvotes or all downvotes, then you even know which type of vote they cast.

Comment: @Servy You have a point there, but isn't that reasoning applicable to our present queues?

Comment: The comment is literally explaining how it doesn't apply to our current queues...so...I mean it applies to them in the sense that it's explaining why they *don't* remove anonymity from voting but your proposed queue would.

Comment: Well in that case, they could work exactly like those review queues I mentioned.

Comment: So they're not going to be just about voting, and are instead going to be focused on other actions with voting as a possible, but not emphasized, action?  That doesn't sound at all like your description of the queue.  You have described the queue as one where voting is the only action.

Comment: That was my original thought, but if it's necessary to do things to protect anonymity I'm open to suggestions. And besides, I don't see the harm in allowing other actions that just voting.

Comment: `"Introduce a new review queue..."` -- do we really need or want yet another review queue of any type, unless there is dire need? It's hard enough to get all the existing queues to be serviced properly, there had better be an extremely pressing need before trying to introduce yet another one.

Comment: *I think we need some way of giving attention to equally good posts* How do you determine whether a low score post is equally as good as a high score post? There is a good chance that bringing attention to low score posts will result in down votes instead of up votes.

Comment: * there's quite a few negatively voted ones too. is meta different?* Probably. Voting on meta is often used to indicate disagreement so a very low scored question here could still be useful (possibly due to highly scored answers).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I cannot say how high the need is, and I don't know anything about how hard it is to get the existing queues serviced properly. This is of course a good argument against.

Comment: @BSMP If they get voted down and potentially get removed, isn't that a good thing?

Comment: I really don't understand the need for this question. Posts with many upvotes only mean that they're relevant and helpful to many users with similar problems. So why stop linking to questions which have the **most** impact on people?

Comment: Your feature request didn't consider this possibility though. It reads like, "Good questions with a low score need more up votes" not "Possibly good questions with low score need exposure to moderation". Also, someone has already suggested deliberately inflicting the Meta effect on posts and that wasn't well received.

Answer (score 15):

No, we are not going to somehow divert attention away from successful posts.

The whole **point** of Stack Overflow is to give people with the same problem a solution. The point is not for every question to get attention and to gain upvotes, or to otherwise spread out votes evenly.

If a question has gained a lot of votes, then that's because that post has been useful to a lot of people. It is then also a good indicator that it'll be useful to *other people in the future*. We want to make sure that those people continue to find those posts helpful to them.

Note that it is *not the score* that is attracting the attention. For posts with a positive score, nothing special is done to boost or lower their visibility (posts with a negative enough score are hidden from the front page). They are purely found via people using search engines. If a new question is a common enough problem, it *will* be found and *will* get votes, over time. We don't need to do anything to help that along.

Comment: I understand that that's the goal. I just happen to believe that a better way to achieve that is to not ignore the heaps of low-score posts laying around. And regarding search engines, I have seen lots of examples on the effect of "high attention implies high attention" on them too. Note that I'm not saying that's the only thing that brings attention, but it sure do help.

Comment: @klutt: but you haven't made any case for there being an actual problem. Show us numbers, bring **proof** that posts with lower vote counts are getting less attention *because of the vote count*, and that that is a problem. I'm asserting, from experience, that there is no attention problem. I've written a lot of answers to a lot of questions, and I find it is the quality of the question and answer taken together, plus there being an actual problem that other people have too, that makes the difference. Sometimes it is surprising what questions are popular (my highest voted answer being one).

Comment: @klutt: but artificially having users being presented with questions to then vote on is an entirely artificial solution to a problem that doesn't exist, and will only serve to skew votes. We want people to vote on content that *actually affects them*, not because they were randomly asked to do so without any more context.

Comment: Unfortunately it would be very hard to bring actual proof of cause. A comparison is listening to music on the radio. How do I prove that song A is equally good as B? It's somewhat, but not completely subjective.

But maybe you're right. Maybe this is a bad idea.

Comment: @klutt: we have a metric tonne of data on posts here, including view and vote counts, as well as age. See http://data.stackexchange.com/ for a web interface where you can query a recent copy of that data (< week old usually). If you can't come up with some minimal objective reasons to justify your proposal, why would anyone put in the (considerable amount of) effort of implementing it?